# avgrund.js не работает template $('.box')

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Используя avgrund.js не срабатывает отображение бокса который указан в template: $('.box'). У бокса задан "display:none;" как указано в документации. Консоль с ошибками молчит.

```js
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#element').avgrund({
        width: 640, // max is 640px
        height: 350, // max is 350px
        showClose: true, // switch to 'true' for enabling close button
        showCloseText: 'закрыть', // type your text for close button
        closeByEscape: true, // enables closing popup by 'Esc'..
        closeByDocument: true, // ..and by clicking document itself
        holderClass: 'element', // lets you name custom class for popin holder..
        overlayClass: 'elementOverlay', // ..and overlay block
        enableStackAnimation: true, // enables different type of popin's animation
        onBlurContainer: '',
        openOnEvent: true, // set to 'false' to init on load
        setEvent: 'click', // use your event like 'mouseover', 'touchmove', etc.
        template: $('.box')

    });
</script>
```

```html
<link href="css/avgrund.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="#" id="element">
Lorem ipsum
</a>

<div class="box" style="display: none;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, rem.
</div>
```